# Why do I get deadlocks when I updated the UI on main thread and background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, locking, deadlock

Of course, I know that the UI update should only be done on the main thread.

First of all, the problem is the code that updates the collection view using RxSwift. I received the above code as drive and am updating the collection view on the main thread, and the below code is updating the collection view on the background thread.

```
    let allMatchObservable = output.allMatchObservable.share()
    
    allMatchObservable
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
        .drive { [weak self] matchs in
            guard let owner = self else { return }
            owner.matchCollectionView.setData(section: .none, matchInfos: matchs.map { MatchInfo(match: $0, owner: User()) })
            owner.matchCountLabel.text = "\(matchs.count)개"
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    let selectSportObservable = output.selectSportObservable.share()
    
    selectSportObservable
        .withUnretained(self)
        .subscribe { owner, matchs in
            owner.matchCollectionView.setData(section: .none, matchInfos: matchs.map { MatchInfo(match: $0, owner: User()) })
            owner.matchCountLabel.text = "\(matchs.count)개"
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And there's a deadlock.

[deadlock capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMXDT.png)

I know I need to update the UI only on the main thread and now I've removed the code that updates the UI from the background thread to fix the error.

But what I'm curious about is, "Why Deadlock?"

[main thread capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFuvr.png)

[background thread capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3hFe.png)

I thought about it when I saw the call stack of the main thread and the background thread when the deadlock occurred.

The background thread called the main thread to process it to update the UI and it went to standby (wait).
(I don't know if this part is correct. I think it will work to update the UI internally on the main because of the wait..)

At the same time, the main thread needs to update the collection view

1. Background Threads - Waiting for the main thread to update the view
2. Main thread - waiting for background thread to update requested view

I guessed that there was a deadlock because we were waiting for each other like this.

But I don't think the reason why the background thread locks is because it calls the main thread.
So I want to know why Xcode detects it as deadlock..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code in code blocks, not as images.

Comment: sorry I edited question

Comment: "Why deadlock?" Somewhere out there on the internets, there's a great essay written by one of the authors of the Java Swing toolkit. It goes into detail about the failures of the AWS toolkit, which allowed graphics methods to be called from different threads, and why they removed that ability from Swing. I don't remember the details, and I can't find the essay, but ISTR, there was something about the conflict between the top-down hierarchy of component classes and the bottom-up nature of event handling that could not be properly resolved if multiple threads were allowed to use the components.

Comment: I think I know, thank you. Could you tell me the address of the ISTR you saw?